# Count number of rows where a row-level flag changed in a monthly snapshot table

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm working in a monthly accounts table that stores a monthly snapshot of the status of an account at the end of each month.  It's partitioned by month.

Example:

```
MNTH_END_DT  ACCT_ID  STATUS_CD
-----------  -------  ---------
1/31/2021    1234     I
2/28/2021    1234     I
3/31/2021    1234     A
```

I'm trying to count all accounts where the STATUS_CD changed to 'A' when the prior month it was still 'I', for any given month.  I'm doing this for about three years worth of data.

I tried to do a self-join but not getting the correct results.  Here a sample of my code

```
SELECT
  a1.mnth_end_dt AS Mth
 ,a2.mnth_end_dt AS Prior_Mth
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN a1.status_cd = 'A' AND a2.status_cd = 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Stat_Chg
 
 FROM acct_tbl AS a1

   INNER JOIN acct_tbl as A2
     ON a1.acct_id = a2.acct_id
     AND a1.mnth_end_dt = LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(a2.mnth_end_dt,-1))
     AND a2.mnth_end_dt BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2021-02-28'

 WHERE a1.mnth_end_dt BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-03-31'

GROUP BY 1,2
```

This approach doesn't really seem to work, as these are the results I get:

```
Mth        Prior_Mth  Stat_Chg
---------  ---------  ---------
1/31/2021  2/28/2021  500
```

Ignore the Stat_Chg values, those are purely illustrational.  But in the other two columns, I would have expected to see the Prior_Mth column being a month older than the Mth column.  E.g. in the example above, I would have expected to see Prior_Mth to be 12/31/2020 instead of 2/28/2021.  And it also only returns one row of results, when I would have expected to 3 rows.

Any suggestions for a better approach to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do a self join.  Assuming there is one row per month:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             LAG(status_cd) OVER (PARTITION BY acct_id ORDER BY mtn_end_dt) as prev_status_cd
      FROM acct_tbl a
     ) a
WHERE status_cd = 'A' AND prev_status_cd = 'I';
```

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon already wrote, no need for a self join, just an aggregation over a Window Function:

```
select mth, Prior_Mth, count(*)
from
 (
    SELECT mnth_end_dt as mth
      ,LAG(mnth_end_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY acct_id ORDER BY mtn_end_dt) as Prior_Mth
    FROM acct_tbl
    QUALIFY -- current status is A
            status_cd = 'A' 
            -- previous status was I
        AND LAG(status_cd) OVER (PARTITION BY acct_id ORDER BY mtn_end_dt) = 'I'
            -- one month ago 
        AND Prior_Mth = oADD_MONTHS(mnth_end_dt,-1)
 ) as dt
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm an idiot.  I just saw my mistake.

In the join, one of my join conditions is

```
a1.mnth_end_dt = LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(a2.mnth_end_dt,-1))
```

I changed that to

```
a2.mnth_end_dt = LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(a1.mnth_end_dt,-1))
```

And now it works.  Leaving this up here in case it's useful to anyone.  But mods, feel free to delete if unnecessary.